# How can I fix my Exchange 2007 outgoing mail from being blocked due to SPF

Tags: exchange-2007, spf

All of a sudden many of my companies emails are being blocked by Hotmail and many others due to SPF.
I've added v=spf1 ip4:66.49.60.115 a mx:hpdist.com ~all to my DNS settings as a TXT record.
But this hasn't helped. 
Is there something server side I need to adjust?

Comment: Do you also have reverse DNS setup as well?

Comment: You need to know where your mail is actually coming from.  Does the header information returned in the bounce messages show this?

Comment: My apologies everyone, I found we had been blacklisted due to a virus.

Answer (score 1):

Test to make sure your SPF record is set up correctly by sending an email to:

```
check-auth-USERNAME=YOURDOMAIN.com@verifier.port25.com
```

The address above will send email authentication results to USERNAME@YOURDOMAIN.com.

Answer (score 0):

When troubleshooting SPF records, I use http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html. This lets me test DNS records before I push them to the server, that way I know they'll work before I deploy them.